# Woocommerce Rest API 401 for NGINX

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I have seen many references to this issue spanning several years but 95% of it relates to Apache. I'm on NGINX hence can't try solutions involving the .htaccess file.

```
{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Since nothing really covers NGINX for this problem I thought of starting a new thread

The first time it happened was when I tried to link Woobotify who automatically generates its own keys. While the keys were created it says it doesn't have read/write error (despite having the right permissions setup)

So I created a new set of keys from within WP and made a direct call (while logged in as admin of course)

as in ://site.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories?consumer_key=ck_8a9b...etc to see if it was on the server-side or Woobotify's and still got the error

If you refer me to http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys
I am too much of a newbie to make use of this information. I either need a step by step or I am willing to hire someone to make it work for me.

LEMP Stack on self-manage VPS

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how I solve it

```
 require "woocommerce_api"

woocommerce = WooCommerce::API.new(
  "https://example.com",
  "consumer_key",
  "consumer_secret",
  {
    wp_json: true,
    version: "wc/v3",
    query_string_auth: true
  }
)
```

OR simply For POSTMAN

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key={{csk}}&consumer_secret={{cs}}
```

The key is query_string_auth: true you need to force basic authentication as query string true under HTTPS